# How to query for first node based on first match within array (and found nodes)?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Well, I'm back here to repropose an old unanswered question. I'll try to explain it better.

I got the following cypher query:

```
neo4j-sh$ start n=node(1344) match (n)-[t:_HAS_TRANSLATION]-(p) return t,p;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t                                   | p                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| :_HAS_TRANSLATION[2224]{of:"value"} | Node[1349]{language:"hi-hi",text:"(>0@"}    |
| :_HAS_TRANSLATION[2223]{of:"value"} | Node[1348]{language:"es-es",text:"hembra"}  |
| :_HAS_TRANSLATION[2222]{of:"value"} | Node[1347]{language:"ru-ru",text:"65=A:89"} |
| :_HAS_TRANSLATION[2221]{of:"value"} | Node[1346]{language:"en-us",text:"female"}  |
| :_HAS_TRANSLATION[2220]{of:"value"} | Node[1345]{language:"it-it",text:"femmina"} |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then I have a dynamic array of languages (can change at any query), in any order, like

```
["fr-fr","jp-jp","en-us", "it-it", "de-de", "ru-ru", "hi-hi"]
```

I need a query to extract only the first[p] depending on the content of the array (in this case Node[1346]{language:"en-us",text:"female"}, because "en-us" is the first occurrence of the array with a macth on the p column.

Thank you again for your patience.

Paolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's a smarter way to solve this, but at least this statement should solve your question:

```
START n=node(1344) match (n)-[t:_HAS_TRANSLATION]-(p)
WITH n, collect(p.language) as languages
WITH n, filter(x in ["fr-fr","jp-jp","en-us","it-it","de-de","ru-ru","hi-hi"] where x in languages)[0] as lang
MATCH (n)-[t:_HAS_TRANSLATION]-(p)
WHERE p.language = lang
RETURN t,p
```